# Chart legend does not appear using SPSS

Tags: charts, legend, spss

I've created a bar chart using SPSS (version 19) commands. The fact is that I want to show a legend with the shown chart but **legend icon** is inactive.

I've read that not all graphs can show a legend, is this true? What is the reason?

My variable is classified as ordinal and has three values: 1= Not satisfied, 2= Satisfied, 3= Totally satisfied